# How do you set a service run as a non user at boot time?

Tags: boot, services, non-root-user

I have a PostgreSQL server that I start on the command line when I log on after I logon. It doesn't run as the normal PostgreSQL service, but under my name with the data stored in my home directory, and on a different port.

How can I get it to start under my own user permissions when the server is rebooted for instance?

The command I normally start is as:

```
cd ~/pgdata01 && /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /home/user/pgdata01/data -c config_file=/home/user/pgdata01/config/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: Does your system use `systemd`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging My system has systemd, but I would prefer something  not dependendent on it as I am not that familiar with it.

Comment: If it was possible with something you are familiar with then you wouldn't have to ask, would you...?

Comment: I have other servers which don't use systemd, and I am in ways to convert them as well. My newer systems use system.d though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the postgresql unit file:

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service \
   /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-userxy.service
```

Then edit postgresql-userxy.service and add `User=` and `WorkingDirectory=` to the `[Service]` section. After that enable the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable postgresql-userxy.service
```